# Is there a way to conditionally block standard Salesforce Informational Inline Text?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

Like the title says, I have a use-case in which I need to block a specific standard Salesforce Information Inline Text Pop-In, specifically the ones concerning Duplicate Matching Rules:
[image]

The reason for this being that we have implemented our own review process to bridge the gap for when matches are found against records users do not have visibility permissions on, so that they can actually read the record's information in a separate modal instead of just being told they don't have access.  So we want to suppress just this part of the messaging on records.  All records is fine, but we want to keep the other regular duplicate review features in place, yet it's appearance goes hand-in-hand with the rules being active, even if 'Alert' is turned off, so I'm just looking for any insight as to how I might suppress this aspect, if possible.

[image]

Component HTML:

```
<template>
<div>
    <template if:true={spinner}>
        <lightning-spinner variant="brand" size="large"></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
</div>
<template if:true={showPopup}>
    <div class="customFont">
        <div>
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class={containerClass}>
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <header class="slds-modal__header slds-modal__header_empty">
                    </header>
                    <div class={containerClass2} id="modal-content-id-1">
                        <div>
                            <template if:true={spinner}>
                                <lightning-spinner variant="brand" size="medium"></lightning-spinner>
                            </template>
                        </div>

                        <template if:true={showWarning}>
                            <div id="mainForm" style="height:35px">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align:center; padding-top:5px">
                                            <span style="font-size:16px; ">
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={warningMessage}></lightning-formatted-text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </template>
                        
                        <template if:true={showItem}>
                            <div class="customFont">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                                <lightning-icon
                                                    icon-name="standard:contact"
                                                    size="large"
                                                    alternative-text="Contact">
                                                </lightning-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <lightning-formatted-text style="font-weight:bold" value={itemRecord.name}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            <br/><br/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Name"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.name}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 15px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Email"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.email}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Account Name"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-url title={itemRecord.accId} label={itemRecord.accName} value={itemRecord.accId} target="_blank" onclick={openItem}></lightning-formatted-url>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 15px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Phone"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.phone}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Title"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.title}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 15px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="SGN_Contact_ID"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.sgnId}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Street"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.accStreet}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 15px">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Owner"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.ownerName}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="City"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.accCity}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="State"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.accState}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #a8a8a8; width: 450px">
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Postal Code"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value={itemRecord.accZip}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <button class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand" onclick={closeItemAlt}>Back</button>
                            </div>
                        </template>

                        <div class={box}>
                            <template if:true={navTab}>
                                <div>
                                    <header class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-align_center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 186, 186)">
                                        <span style="text-align:center; font-size: 22px; color:grey">
                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Active Duplicate Records"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                            <br/>
                                            <br/>
                                        </span>
                                    </header>
                                    <br/>
                                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" style="background-color:rgb(231, 231, 231)">
                                        <br/>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div style="text-align:center">
                                                            <br/>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Click on a contact's name below to review their records."></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <br/>
                                        <template for:each={duplicates} for:item="dup">
                                            <table key={dup.Id} style="border:1px solid rgb(196, 186, 186); width:500px; margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px; background-color:white">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                                                        <lightning-icon
                                                            icon-name="standard:contact"
                                                            size="large"
                                                            alternative-text="Contact">
                                                        </lightning-icon>
                                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text style="font-weight:bold" value={dup.Name}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        <br/>
                                                        <br/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value="Name:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <lightning-formatted-url title={dup.Id} label={dup.Name} value={dup.Id} target="_blank" onclick={openItemAlt}></lightning-formatted-url>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value="Account Name:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <lightning-formatted-url title={dup.Account.Id} label={dup.Account.Name} value={dup.Account.Id} target="_blank" onclick={openItem}></lightning-formatted-url>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value="Email:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value={dup.Email}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value="Phone:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value={dup.Phone}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value="Owner:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <lightning-formatted-text value={dup.Owner.Name}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <br key={dup.Id}/>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <br key={dup.Id}/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr style="border-top:1px solid rgb(196, 186, 186)">
                                                    <td colspan="2">
                                                        <div style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px">
                                                            <lightning-button variant="brand" class="button-override" onclick={deleteReplaceItem} title={dup.Id} label="Use This Contact to Replace the Duplicate"></lightning-button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        </template>
                                    </div>
                                    <br/>
                                </div>
                                <br/>
                            </template>
                            <template if:true={warningTab}>
                                    <div>
                                        <header class="slds-text-heading_small slds-text-align_center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(196, 186, 186)" >
                                            <span style="text-align:center; font-size: 22px; color:grey">
                                                <lightning-formatted-text value="Inactive Duplicate Records"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                <br/>
                                                <br/>
                                            </span>
                                        </header>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" style="background-color:rgb(231, 231, 231)">
                                            <br/>
                                            <table>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div style="text-align:center">
                                                            <br/>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Click on a contact's name below to review their records."></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                            <br/>
                                            <template for:each={deactivatedDuplicates} for:item="dup">
                                                <table key={dup.Id} style="border:1px solid rgb(196, 186, 186); width:500px; margin-right: 30px; margin-left: 30px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:10px; background-color:white">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="2" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
                                                            <lightning-icon
                                                                icon-name="standard:contact"
                                                                size="large"
                                                                alternative-text="Contact">
                                                            </lightning-icon>
                                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text style="font-weight:bold" value={dup.Name}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                            <br/>
                                                            <br/>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Name:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-url title={dup.Id} label={dup.Name} value={dup.Id} target="_blank" onclick={openItemAlt}></lightning-formatted-url>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Account Name:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-url title={dup.Account.Id} label={dup.Account.Name} value={dup.Account.Id} target="_blank" onclick={openItem}></lightning-formatted-url>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Email:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value={dup.Email}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Phone:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value={dup.Phone}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding-left: 10px;">
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="Owner:"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <lightning-formatted-text value={dup.Owner.Name}></lightning-formatted-text>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <br key={dup.Id}/>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <br key={dup.Id}/>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr style="border-top:1px solid rgb(196, 186, 186)">
                                                        <td colspan="2">
                                                            <div style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px">
                                                                <lightning-button variant="brand" class="button-override" onclick={reactivateReplaceItem} title={dup.Id} label="Reactivate This Contact to Replace the Duplicate"></lightning-button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <br key={dup.Id}/><br key={dup.Id}/><br key={dup.Id}/>
                                            </template>
                                            <br/>
                                        </div>
                                        <br/>
                                    </div>
                            </template>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <template if:true={showFooter}>
                    <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                        <template if:true={showTab}>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align:center;">
                                        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={openTab}>View Duplicates</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={showOptions}>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                                            <lightning-formatted-text value="You may also choose to accept your original entry as a valid record, or stop the process and remove it, by clicking one of the buttons below"></lightning-formatted-text>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align:center;">
                                            <br/>
                                            <button class="slds-button slds-button_outline-brand" onclick={cancelRemove}>Cancel and Remove This New Contact</button>
                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={acceptEntry}>Continue and Create This New Contact</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            </template>
                    </footer>
                    </template>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Thanks

Comment: I guess you are referring to the duplicate record message in the new record creation page. I don't think you can hide this in the standard page, but if you override the new button with your own custom page/ component, then you would have control over what needs to be displayed. Could you add some more details about how you have the custom solution in place now?

Comment: It's not the new record creation page itself.  There we've been able to bypass its appearance by leaving the 'Alert' option unchecked in the duplicate rule settings.  This is appearing when users open the records which may be duplicates immediately after creating them.  Any other time past the first time they look at the record after saving it would be fine if it showed up, but because our new process goes into action as soon as the record is saved and the user is navigated to that new page the appearance of the pop-in at that time has the potential to confuse viewers so we'd like to stop it.

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in my dev org. Could you update the question with exact sequence of steps to be followed for replicating this issue?

Comment: 1) User chooses to enter a new contact record.  They are presented with the standard Salesforce record entry screen for their applicable record type.  2) Because duplicate matching alerts are turned off they are allowed to save without incident. 3) They are directed to the record they created upon save.  4) If there is a duplicate of the record they entered our custom process will trigger and display a warning modal preventing them from proceeding until they have reviewed the records.  This is also where the Standard Salesforce Inline Toast Message appears and interferes with the display.

Comment: So, this standard inline informational text appear on the (custom developed) warning modal? If yes, then you should post some the code snippet to figure out why the info is being displayed.

Comment: It's not displaying within the modal, but because the modal component is housed within the standard Contact record lightning page the unwanted message is firing because it's coming from the standard page's messaging service, so I'm trying to either suppress that messaging, or configure the modal in such a way that it can supersede anything like that coming to the foreground/displaying in the background.

Comment: Would you be able to add some full page screenshots? May be provide some code snippet? So I can try to replicate this at my end.

Comment: Updated original post with example shot and component markup.

Comment: The updated screenshot gives a very clear picture of the problem. Your component HTML doesn't seem to have any problem. Check if the posted answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your record page must have the **Potential Duplicates** component in it, which would normally show up as shown below (*in the page edit mode*).

[image]

In your case, the *Display Options* attribute for this component might be set to *Show Toast*, so it must look like the screenshot given below (*in the page edit mode*). **Removing this component from the record page should fix your problem**.

[image]

***Update:** As mentioned by @CMielczarski is the comments, if the requirement mandates retaining this standard component, then the `Display Options` attribute for this component must be set to `Card Only`.*

Comment: You were correct.  That original standard component was sort of tucked out of the way on the record page itself and, while we still wanted the card to be available for subsequent viewings so we couldn't take it completely off the page, simply switching that display option to Card only instead of Show Toast seems to have accomplished what we needed it to do.  Thanks for the patience in working through the options.